# Azure active directory with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

we have an ASP.NET MVC web application where we azure b2c authentication. There are several controllers and views in mvc application. Whenever user wants to access to controller we have checking whether he is signed in or not? On the basis of that if user is already signed then only we are giving access to him. On every controller's .cs file we have put code like :

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
       some code;
        return View();
      }
      else
      {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
      }
```

This type of code on each action method of controller. Its working fine but most of the times it automatically kicked user out of the system frequently on login page to re-sign again.

Ca anyone tell me how can I centarlized this type of code in mvc application for each controller so that it should not kicked me out of the system. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict access to an ASP.NET MVC view, you restrict access to the action method that renders the view. To accomplish this, the MVC framework provides the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) class.

> Its working fine but most of the times it automatically kicked user out of the system frequently on login page to re-sign again.

Did you mean that that after the web session is expired, then the web application redirect the web request to the login page? If I understood correctly, this is a expected behavior. And if you want the web application to keep alive when the user is active, you can enable the [SlidingExpiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Does authorize attribute provides redirection functionality. I mean, if user is looged in then if we enter the urls specific to application like suppose "localhost:44316/Affiliated/Affiliates/115" then user can view this url. But when user is logged out and if somebody puts this url then the page should be redirect to login page.

Comment: To redirect to the specific page automatically if the web app got the `401` error, you need to set the [LoginPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.loginpath(v=vs.113).aspx).